# Chrome can't find offsetTop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

style.top  offsetTop in chrome is 'object DOM Window',
it doesn't give a integer, why.
I google such issue but seems I am the only one having such a problem.

They works well in firefox.
How to get an element's offsetTop in Chrome.

code:

```
<input type="button"id='test' value="clickme"/>
<script>
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click',function(){
    alert(this.offsetTop);
    top = this.offsetTop;
    alert(top);
},true)
</script>
```

Well, it's very interesting, it works in the alert function but can't be stored.

Comment: hmm Googling comes up with nothing. I do see that jQuery has a similar bug, but it just returns a different value. Please supply code to help us test it.

Comment: Thanks drow, the code has been updated. Would you mind telling me the values you get from the above codes? I hope it's the problem only in my browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `window.top` already is a built-in property in the browsers. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top

This property is read-only ([see here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#the-window-object)):

```
readonly attribute WindowProxy top;
```

which means that the assignment `top = this.offsetTop` doesn't do anything.

This is a classic case of an issue that arises because of global namespace pollution. Don't do it. Instead, declare your variables locally:

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var top = this.offsetTop;
    alert(top);
}, true);
```

Comment: Sime Vidas, you are terrific. Thanks very much, notably your answering speed.